# background color disappears on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

my problem is that when the screen gets under 600px then navbar becomes a dropdown navbar. Now the problem is that when you scroll down 100px the navbar gets a black background but when i wanna open the dropdown menu the black background disappears...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="costume.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Connect stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="costume.scss">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" align="left">
              <a href=""><p>Home</p></a>
              <a href=""><p>Portfolio</p></a>
              <a href=""><p>About</p></a>
              <a href=""><p>Impressum</p></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="banner topnav"></div>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>

  <script>
        $(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
              $('div#myTopnav').addClass('scrolled');
        } else {
              $('div#myTopnav ').removeClass('scrolled');
                    }
              });
        });

        $(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
              $('a').addClass('scrolled2');
        } else {
              $('a').removeClass('scrolled2');
                    }
              });
        });


        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

.topnav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 50px;;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.35s all ease;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.topnav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1001;
 }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1001;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:hover {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
 }
 }

.banner {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431492299426-
2ea1ce429cc0?ixlib=rb-
0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=135705633ad6367a0565fceae4a57372');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

.scrolled {
  min-height: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.35s all ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.85;

}

.scrolled2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.95;

  .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: red;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVYmKZ <-- use chrome 
https://jsfiddle.net/he7uhnya/

there is a gif so you can see what i mean https://gyazo.com/aa5c558cea87f645a32817cba5ff56db

Comment: jsFiddle could help...

Comment: Could you create a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code? Then it's easier for us to help you out.

Comment: i added a link but open it in chrome ... ironically some things dont work in firefox even though I always use firefox

Comment: on my localfile the font color is black not blue like in this case https://jsfiddle.net/he7uhnya/ and he codepen one

Comment: I have added the solution kindly check the same and if you need anything just comment here.Give vote if you like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this script tag-

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
          $('div#myTopnav').addClass('scrolled');
          $('a').addClass('scrolled2');
       } 
       else {
          $('div#myTopnav ').removeClass('scrolled');
          $('a').removeClass('scrolled2');
        }
      });
    function myFunction() {
        $("#myTopnav").toggleClass('responsive');

    }

 </script>
```

Comment: ok i tryed it but it doesnt work either
i have a gif so u see what i mean https://gyazo.com/aa5c558cea87f645a32817cba5ff56db

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/pritamk94/pen/vmzqEr)
https://codepen.io/pritamk94/pen/vmzqEr
see this

Comment: nothing same as it was given in the solution.you need to replace the entire script tag with my solution script,

Comment: hmm i did  ... but now i cleared the cache maybe that was the problem but now it work thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

you can use bootstrap for the better navbars

refer also : https://codepen.io/anoopnockson/pen/dWqEWN

```css
.body{
padding-top:10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<div class="body" >
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>

<label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
</div>
```